# Access audios and videos in windows phone 8

Tags: file, cordova, windows-phone-8, media

I am working on an app for Windows Phone 8 with PhoneGap. What I want to achieve is to list all videos and audios in list on page.
I googled things but could not find anything useful and PhoneGap API too. What are the ways wherein we can access all the audios and videos (mp3 and mp4).

Thanks is advance.

Comment: what other phones are you intenting to support?

Comment: if that is so, i suggest you build a native html/javascript app using the .net framework

Comment: Actually the app I am working on is already developed and I have a feature to integrate in this existing app. Can I create a custom plugin XAML page to access and list down files>

Comment: There is a plugin development guide: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide
however - migrating a html/javascript phonegap app into a html/javascript .net WP-app might be even simpler